# Fiiling the compose message at opening

Tags: thunderbird-addon

I'm desesperatly seeking for a way to fill in the compose message when it opens, in a boostraped (restartless) TB add-on.

This is something that I did in my non-bootstraped add-on [RemindIt](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/thunderbird/addon/remindit/)

Thanks to [Superjos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989864/get-sender-and-recipients-in-thunderbird-extension-upon-sending-message) I was able to manage the different listeners, and get the compose message filled with my custom message when it opened.

But... this works only for new (non recycled) windows. If I close a compose window, then click on "new message", it is recycled (I guess) and the "load" event is not fired.

I tried different tricks (see for example onComposeInit2), but at the end, I'm not able to alter compose message for non new windows, even if it looks like my addon is calling the editing method (this is what one can see in the log).

Any ideas ?

See my test/bootstrap.js code :

```
function log(s){
    Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService).logStringMessage("test: "+s);
}
// Thanks (a lot ! ) to Superjos :
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989864/get-sender-and-recipients-in-thunderbird-extension-upon-sending-message

var winListener={
    onOpenWindow: function(win){
    compose=win.docShell.
      QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).
      getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
    compose.addEventListener('compose-window-init', winListener.onComposeInit, true);

    },
    onComposeInit: function(event){
    var document=event.currentTarget.document;   
    var edit=document.getElementById("content-frame");
    edit.addEventListener("load",winListener.onComposeLoad,true);

    log("compose init "+event.currentTarget);

    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type,winListener.onComposeInit , true);

    },


    onComposeLoad: function(event){
    var edit=event.currentTarget;
    var editor=edit.getHTMLEditor(edit.contentWindow);
    log("compose load");
    winListener.alterMessage(editor);
    },
    alterMessage: function(editor){
    var msg="Hello<br>";
    editor.insertHTML(msg);
    log("alter message "+editor);
    },

    onComposeInit2: function(event){
    var document=event.currentTarget.document;   
    var edit=document.getElementById("content-frame");
    edit.addEventListener("load",winListener.onComposeLoad,true);

    log("compose init "+event.currentTarget);

    var editor=edit.getHTMLEditor(edit.contentWindow);
    if( editor!=null ){
        // the editor is ready, remove load event listener
        edit.removeEventListener("load",winListener.onComposeLoad,true);
        // and call the method to alter message
        winListener.alterMessage(editor);
    }
    //edit.addEventListener("focus",winListener.onFocus,true);
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type,winListener.onComposeInit2 , true);

    },
    /*
    onFocus: function(event){
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener("focus",winListener.onFocus,true);
    var edit=event.currentTarget;
    var editor=edit.getHTMLEditor(edit.contentWindow);
    winListener.alterMessage(editor);
    log("focus");
    },
    onComposeClose: function(event){
    var document=event.currentTarget.document;   
    var edit=document.getElementById("content-frame");
    edit.addEventListener("focus",winListener.onFocus,true);
    log("close");

    }
*/

}



function startup(aData, aReason) {
    log("startup");

var windowMediator = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].
  getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);

windowMediator.addListener(winListener);


}

function shutdown(aData, aReason) {
    log("shutdown");
    var windowMediator = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);  
    windowMediator.removeListener(winListener);

}

function install(aData, aReason) { 

    log("install");


}

function uninstall(aData, aReason) {
    log("uninstall");


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from this http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=450474
There is a compose-window-reopen event that is fired when the window is reopen.