# Getting Thunderbird's email editor object from a restartless (bootstrapped) addon

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm creating a restartless (bootstrapped) addon for Thunderbird to replicate the functionality of an overlay-based addon I made years ago. The desire is to manipulate some of the text in the new email's body. In [the old overlay version](http://www.mozdev.org/source/browse/autorewrap/src/autorewrap/content/autorewrapComposeOverlay.js?rev=1.5;content-type=text%2Fx-cvsweb-markup), it was pretty straightforward: I could just use the gMsgCompose object. How do I get the gMsgCompose object for a compose window in a restartless addon?

Here's my code right now. For a while I thought that edElem was nearly what I wanted, which is why I'm test-dumping edElem.editortype (which should be either "textmail" or "htmlmail" when I really do have the right object).

```
    'use strict';

    const Cc = Components.classes;
    const Ci = Components.interfaces;
    const Cu = Components.utils;

    Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

    function startup(data, reason)
    {
        Services.wm.addListener(MyAddon.windowListener);
    }

    function shutdown(data, reason)
    {
        Services.wm.removeListener(MyAddon.windowListener);
    }

    function install(aData, aReason) { }
    function uninstall(aData, aReason) { }

    if(!MyAddon) var MyAddon = {};
    MyAddon.windowListener = {
        onOpenWindow: function(aXULWindow) {
            let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow
                .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
            if (!aDOMWindow) return;

            aDOMWindow.addEventListener("load", function _cl_load(event){
                aDOMWindow.removeEventListener("load", _cl_load, false);
                MyAddon.handleOpenWindow(aDOMWindow, event.target);
            }, false);
        }
    }; // MyAddon.windowListener

    MyAddon.handleOpenWindow = function(aDOMWindow, DOMdocument) {
        if(DOMdocument.documentURI != "chrome://messenger/content/messengercompose/messengercompose.xul")
            return;
        let edWindow = DOMdocument.documentElement;
        // Just to be sure
        if(edWindow.id != 'msgcomposeWindow')
            return;

        let edElem = DOMdocument.getElementById("content-frame");

        /* I thought edElem was the element I want, but the following
         * returns an empty result, which I take to mean the element isn't
         * fully loaded yet.
         */
        dump("XXX handleOpenWindow: edElem.editortype="+edElem.editortype+"\n");

        /* Adding a listener to this element doesn't get the behaviour
         * I want either. I've tried hooking several events
         * in the following fashion, and the event handler code doesn't
         * execute for any of them, so maybe edElem isn't what I want.
         */
        [ "load",
          "unload",
          "compose-window-init",
          "compose-window-close",
          "compose-fields-ready",
          "compose-send-message",
        ].forEach(function(eventName) {
            edElem.addEventListener(eventName, function _eE_FIXME(event){
                dump("XXX "+eventName+": edElem.editortype="+edElem.editortype+"\n");
            }, false);
        });

        /* So, how do I get control of the editor,
         * so I can read and play with its content?
         */

    }; // MyAddon.handleOpenWindow
```

The only question I found on stackoverflow that's close to what I want is [Get sender and recipients in Thunderbird extension upon sending message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989864/get-sender-and-recipients-in-thunderbird-extension-upon-sending-message). I've tried what they do there, but all it seems to do is give me an alternate way of getting the compose window as a whole, which I can already get.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an ugly stub with a timer in the `onOpenWindow`:

```
domWindow.setTimeout( function() { uploadHook( domWindow ); }, 500 );
```

So then (in `uploadHook`) I can get editor with:

```
var editorNode = domWindow.document.getElementById("content-frame");
// GetCurrentEditor() equivalent:
nsIEditor = editorNode.getEditor(editorNode.contentWindow)
```

But looking for a better solution.

Comment: @Jaap: the question is pretty the same. I even have an answer (may be helpful to someone else), but I now that it is not the best one possible. Should I delete it?

Comment: I got misguided by you last sentence, which indicated at first to me you were looking for an answer. I will remove my comments & you just leave your answer as it is (or improve it with a better solution ;-) )